# Regiochemistry and stereochemistry in synthesis of alcohols from cycloalkenes through oxymercuration and hydroboration

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

I have been posting several practice final questions for my organic exam next Tuesday. I have worked through all the questions, but my prof does not post the answers. I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Draw full structures, including any relevant stereochemistry of the organic products expected in each of the following reactions:

[image]

One reaction uses a syn addition, and the other uses oxymercuration. Question: for the oxymercuration, this is anti-Markovnikov because the hydrogen doesn't end up on the most substituted carbon, right?

Comment: Markovnikov addition means that the hydrogen ends up on the less substituted carbon. That means oxymercuration gives the Markovnikov product. Go back and think about the simple addition of HBr. I feel like you could have checked a textbook first or the Internet though. Most textbooks I know would have said exactly the same thing that I did: hydroboration is anti-Markovnikov and oxymercuration is Markovnikov.